# Splitting a sequence where a character is repeated exactly two times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'd like to split a sequence where a character is repeated exactly two times, and preserve the separating part, too. Is there a shorter regular expression for that?

```
In [101]: seq='tgtttccgagtgacccgagatagaaacttaccgga'

In [102]: l=[ s for s in re.split(r"(?<!a)(a{2})(?!a)|(?<!g)(g{2})(?!g)|(?<!c)(c{2})(?!c)|(?<!t)(t{2})(?!t)",seq) if s ]

In [103]: l
Out[103]: ['tgttt', 'cc', 'gagtgacccgagatagaaac', 'tt', 'a', 'cc', 'gg', 'a']

In [104]: ''.join(l)==seq
Out[104]: True
```

Comment: There are easier solutions than regex for this.

Comment: Use a regex back reference `r'(.)\1'` The `\1` references the group in the `(.)` https://regex101.com/r/BKPiV2/1

Comment: Well, not any better, I guess: `l=re.sub(r'([a-z])(?<!\1{2})\1(?!\1)', r'|\g<0>|', s).replace('||', '|').split('|')`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, It's great! Thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you can't put a backreference inside a lookbehind.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Well, I can, I [did, and Python did not object](https://ideone.com/hwd441).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: with [Python 3.4](https://eval.in/1039486) (and probably previous versions), it returns:  `tgt|tt||cc|gagtgac|cc|gagataga|aa|c|tt|a|cc||gg|a` (The lookbehind seems to be simply ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> seq='tgtttccgagtgacccgagatagaaacttaccgga'
>>> [m[0] for m in re.findall(r'((?:(.)(?!\2)|(.)\3\3+)+|..)', seq)]
['tgttt', 'cc', 'gagtgacccgagatagaaac', 'tt', 'a', 'cc', 'gg', 'a']
```

The main idea is to write an always successful pattern, this way, the regex engine doesn't have to test each position in the string with 4 alternatives (aa,cc,gg,tt + the lookarounds) for nothing most of the time. All the matches are consecutive.

The pattern has two parts, the first `(?:(.)(?!\2)|(.)\3\3+)+` describes all that isn't exactly two same characters (a single character `(.)(?!\2)` or more than two same characters `(.)\3\3+`) and is repeated greedily, the second part matches the remaining case with `..`

Feel free to replace all the dots with `[actg]` if needed.

---

with `re.finditer`:

```
[mo.group(0) for mo in re.finditer(r'(?:(.)(?!\1)|(.)\2\2+)+|..', seq)]
```

or starting with Python 3.6:

```
[mo[0] for mo in re.finditer(r'(?:(.)(?!\1)|(.)\2\2+)+|..', seq)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of regex, using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
def get_combos(d):
  for a, b in d:
    if a:
      yield from b
    else:
      yield ''.join(b)

seq='tgtttccgagtgacccgagatagaaacttaccgga'
new_seq = [''.join(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(seq)]
final_result = list(get_combos([[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(new_seq, key=lambda x:len(x) == 2 and x[0] == x[1])]))
```

Output:

```
['tgttt', 'cc', 'gagtgacccgagatagaaac', 'tt', 'a', 'cc', 'gg', 'a']
```